# Changing FFT of my Signal Source block automatically

Tags: python, gnuradio

I have made my own signal source block in GNURadio by coding the Python Module block.
Now my aim is to change the FFT of it automatically after few seconds or milliseconds.

The way i have coded my signal source block is that at different pseudo random numbers, output_items is assigned different frequencies,for which i have used for loop. But the issue is that the FFT plot shows only when the 'return' statement in work() function is encountered. And till the time 'return' is reached, all of iterations get finished already hence producing the frequency of last iteration only, so in FFT plot only the frequency corresponding to last pseudo-random code generated shows up (which is not desired).

Long story cut short is i want to somehow show the output for each iteration of for loop, but 'return' statement doesn't let me do it. It returns only the last iteration frequency.

```
   work(self, input_items, output_items)
             .
             .
    local_fs =4096
    SINTAB= empty([len(output_items[0])])
    SINTAB = np.zeros((4096),dtype=complex)
    for i in range(0,len(output_items[0])-1):
        SINTAB[i]=  math.sin(2*3.14*(i)/local_fs)-1j*math.cos(2*3.14*(i)/local_fs)

    for f_local_index in range( 0 , 7):

        check = sub_seed_hop_freq[f_local_index]

        if check==1:
            Freq = 0.5e6;

        elif check==2:
            Freq = 1e6;

        elif check==3:
            Freq = 1.5e6;
        payload_transmitted_at = Freq
        .
        . (payload_step is assigned values in if else statements depending 
           upon the corresponding frequencies in above if else  )
        .

        for i in range (0 , len(output_items[0])-1):
           #print(len(output_items[0])-1)
           output_items[0][i] = SINTAB[int(round(index_f))]
            #local_I_mega_sub_seed(i) = COSTAB(round(index_f));

            index_f = index_f + payload_step

            #print(payload_step)
            if index_f>len(output_items[0])-1:
                index_f = index_f - len(output_items[0])
    return len(output_items[0])
```

Rest is the code to convert Freq into sine wave (not putting because of lengthiness)
sub_seed_hop_freq is a vector of random numbers (pseudo random)

Comment: I think your code is really missing the important part: What does "output_items is assigned different frequencies" mean?

Comment: and your question makes no sense at all "only when the return statement is reached": Of course! When the return statement is not reached (how should that ever happen?!), that's when the block produces a chunk of items, and not before. I think you might be misunderstanding what the work() function is for, alltogether.

Comment: output_items produce different frequency. Assignment in terms of an equation.

Comment: My issue is not with return statement execution, i understand its purpose. My point is that i want to return for all iterations which is not possible because once returned is returned! And is only possible for 1 iteration of course.

Comment: you still don't explain what "output_items produce different frequency" means. `output_items` is a vector.

Comment: You really seem to be having a misconception about either GNU Radio or Python. What would "return for all iterations" even mean?! What is an iteration, if not a call to `work`, which always ends in the `return` statement?

Comment: Iteration of 'for' loop.

Comment: again, if you want to talk about your `for` loop, you're missing the relevant part of your code. Voting to close this question as unclear.

Comment: Edited, kindly review

Comment: sorry, this is still not the full code, and you still don't understand that work finishes no earlier than you `return`.

Comment: Wait let me tell you what i know and what i want to do: i have made my own block with its code written in work() function. And in that unless return statement is executed, No output will be showed( obviously programming basics) no matter what i write. but once output_items has its values and the function is returned output is ready to be shown.  Now i want output_items to have values get returned, have different values get returned (showing different output in FFT) and so on for 7 iterations as shown in the code. This where i am stuck!

Comment: I am trying my best to convey what i want to do and what is my problem. Kindly do give it a look one last time.

Comment: **Long story cut short is i want to somehow show the output for each iteration of for loop, but 'return' statement doesn't let me do it.** yeah, that's because that's how GNU Radio works. As said – you misunderstanding how GNU Radio works. As I said in my [second comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56206465/changing-fft-of-my-signal-source-block-automatically?noredirect=1#comment99039636_56206465): only when the work functions finishes items are passed on to the next block.

Comment: You mean i am still misunderstood? Will i not be able to do what i want? I still don't know whether you got my point or not. . .

Comment: how many times do you want me to repeat that? Yes, you have misunderstood. No, what you want to do does not work.

Comment: Fine, thank you for bearing!